# How to change button.text of all the buttons you created in code (NOT the manually created buttons)? C#

Tags: c#, forms, visual-studio, button

my goal is I want to name each letter of a word be put into individual buttons and I also want to shuffle or re arrange those letters that are on the buttons.. so basically it will look like this...

H P E L
(each letter represents a button)

those button should re arrange when a button is clicked (would be like a shuffle button)

because I'm trying to make my own version of a text twist game from scratch.. so i created my buttons using a loop to save effort.

```
private void addButtonLetters()
    {
         string testabc = "abc";
         shuffled = new string(testabc.OrderBy(r => RNDM.Next(i, 4)).ToArray());

        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {

            newButton = new Button();
            newButton.Size = new Size(75, 41);
            newButton.Location = new Point(11 + 80 * i, 66);
            newButton.Text = shuffled[i].ToString();
            newButton.Click += buttonClicked; //click handler
            letters[i] = newButton;
            this.Controls.Add(letters[i]);


        }
    }
```

from this point I wanted to shuffle the letters on each button when i try to click a button that is suppose to be re arranging the letters.... 
what I tried to do is I just call the 'addButtonLetter();' event every time i try to click the (suppose to be shuffle) because I'm assuming it would just re create a new set of re arranged buttons but it did not and did nothing.. So I just tried doing

```
string testabc = "abc";
shuffled = new string(testabc.OrderBy(r => RNDM.Next(i, 4)).ToArray());

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
       newButton.Text = shuffled[i].ToString();
    }
```

and it will only change the last button's letter but i want to change all three! I even found out that the loop was useless because when i removed it, it still only changes the last button...

I need suggestion on how I could change all of the buttons text since I can't rename it one by one manually...

Do I need to run through all the buttons I created and do it from there? if so how? any suggestion would be helpful. I tried to make my question as clear as possible and put as much info i could give i hope all the information I provided was clear and helpful to those who want to help... if not just ask me anything that I could clear up! Thank you in advance!

Note: this is my test code so i don't mess with my original one... my original one will contain more buttons and i'm trying baby steps first...

Comment: Put the created buttons into a list and from there you can modify them however you want.

Comment: You need to use `letters` array to access the button and set it's text. something like `letters[i].Text = suffled[i].ToString();`. I assume that the `letters` is an array of Button.

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned like "I'm trying to make my own version of a text twist game from scratch" then u can just shuffle the letter, Hope this will help you :-

```
List<string> source =new List<string>();
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        source.Add("a");
        source.Add("b");
        source.Add("c");
        source.Add("d");
        source.Add("e");
        SetButtonText(source);
    }

    private void SetButtonText(List<string> source)
    {
        button1.Text = source[0];
        button2.Text = source[1];
        button3.Text = source[2];
        button4.Text = source[3];
        button5.Text = source[4];
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var rnd = new Random();
        var newsource = source.OrderBy(item => rnd.Next());
        SetButtonText(newsource.ToList());

    }
```

If u want to change the button location then try this :-

```
    private void GetAllControl(Control c, List<Control> list)
    {
        foreach (Control control in c.Controls)
        {
            list.Add(control);

            if (control.GetType() == typeof(Panel))
                GetAllControl(control, list);
        }
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<Rectangle> btnLocation = new List<Rectangle>();
        List<Control> btnList = new List<Control>();
        GetAllControl(this, btnList);
        foreach (Control control in btnList)
        {
            if (control.Text != "Shuffle")
            {
                btnLocation.Add(control.Bounds);
            }
        }
        var rnd = new Random();
        var newsource = btnLocation.OrderBy(item => rnd.Next()).ToList();
        int i = 0;
        foreach (Control control in btnList)
        {
            if (control.Text != "Shuffle")
            {
                control.Bounds = newsource[i];
            }
            i++;
        }
    }
```

I have tested both it's working ;)